# error with rviz and .vcg file

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is the error when following the "Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch" tutorial with the command:

```
$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf.
ERROR: the config file '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/urdf.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
       New config files have a .rviz extension and use YAML formatting.  The format changed
       between Fuerte and Groovy.  There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 7228, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/urdf.vcg __name:=rviz __log:=/home/jaysin/.ros/log/4bfd76c6-fce3-11e2-9283-902b344ab2c8/rviz-3.log].
log file: /home/jaysin/.ros/log/4bfd76c6-fce3-11e2-9283-902b344ab2c8/rviz-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70957/error-with-rviz-and-.vcg-file/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2013-08-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error message states, the [RViz configuration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#Configurations) format has changed.

As from the [URDF tutorial sources](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/commit/2f8f327078f0c4e3906e957283ad362e87bbd21e) that has already been fixed three months ago.

Where do you cloned your `urdf_tutorial` package from? And when, is it up to date? Try a `git pull`. Did you checked out another branch or something?

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on 2013-08-05**:
i entered the command : rosdep install urdf_tutorial
i have both urdf.rviz and urdf.vcg in it just like on the github

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-08-05**:
And which one is linked within in `display.launch`? As from the commit that should be *urdf.rviz*.

**Comment by [vijyant](https://answers.ros.org/users/5854/vijyant/) on 2013-08-10**:
I am also facing the same problem. please explain in detail.